# Get the total count of messages sent to/from a number - Twilio Python API

Tags: python, twilio

We are using Twilio to send messages and want to get a count of messages that have been sent by a number and recieved by the same number.

Right now we are trying to do something along the lines like:

```
messagesTo = twilioClient.messages.list({ 
                    "DateSent>"   : startDate,
                    "DateSent<"   : endDate,
                    "to"          : number
                    })

messagesFrom = twilioClient.messages.list({ 
                    "DateSent>"   : startDate,
                    "DateSent<"   : endDate,
                    "from_"       : number
                    })

count = len(messagesTo) + len(messagesFrom)
```

However we are running into 2 problems.

First, the

```
twilioClient.messages.list({ 
                "DateSent>"   : startDate,
                "DateSent<"   : endDate,
                "to"          : number
                })
```

is always returning empty with the to field used

Second, we always get only a maximum of 50 results.

Is there a way to just use the parameters to get the count rather then the messages?

Answer (score 1):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

I'm afraid API results do not include the total number of results. This was a compromise taken mainly for performance reasons. There was a blog post that explained [the decisions made around pagination](https://www.twilio.com/engineering/2015/04/16/replacing-absolute-paging-with-relative-paging) here.

If you really do need to count the messages, you can page through the list yourself. Firstly, you can get up to 1000 messages per page, by [setting the `PageSize` attribute to 1000](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/response#response-formats-list-paging-information).

With the Python helper library, you can also [iterate through all results using the `iter` method, as explained here](http://twilio-python.readthedocs.io/en/latest/usage/basics.html#listing-all-resources).

Let me know if that helps at all.

Comment: Thanks for that. Does the iter method allow for the use of 'to', 'from_', and 'dateSent' like list does in the Python Helper?

Comment: [It sure does!](https://github.com/twilio/twilio-python/blob/master/twilio/rest/resources/messages.py#L146-L147)